# UTC time explanation

Tags: time, timezone, utc

Can anybody explain me what it means when I have the following time:

2012-12-28T18:12:33+01:00

I'm new to the whole datetime stuff and I can't find a good explanation on the web.

Currently I'm in Holland. So does it mean:

2012-12-28T18:12:33+01:00 = 2012-12-28 19:12:33

or

2012-12-28T18:12:33+01:00 = 2012-12-28 17:12:33

or

2012-12-28T18:12:33+01:00 = 2012-12-28 18:12:33

Answer (score 0, accepted):

International Standard `ISO 8601` specifies numeric representations of date and time.

YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sTZD (eg 1997-07-16T19:20:30.45+01:00)
where:

```
 YYYY = four-digit year
 MM   = two-digit month (01=January, etc.)
 DD   = two-digit day of month (01 through 31)
 hh   = two digits of hour (00 through 23) (am/pm NOT allowed)
 mm   = two digits of minute (00 through 59)
 ss   = two digits of second (00 through 59)
 s    = one or more digits representing a decimal fraction of a second
 TZD  = time zone designator (Z or +hh:mm or -hh:mm)
```

Times are expressed in UTC (Coordinated Universal Time), with a special UTC designator ("Z").
Times are expressed in `local time`, together with a time zone offset in hours and minutes. A time zone offset of "+hh:mm" indicates that the date/time uses a **local time zone which is "hh" hours and "mm" minutes ahead of UTC**. A time zone offset of "-hh:mm" indicates that the date/time uses a `local time` zone which is "hh" hours and "mm" minutes behind UTC.

In your case: 2012-12-28T18:12:33+01:00 = 2012-12-28 18:12:33 is true. Meaning the time in Holland is 18:12 and you are 1 hour ahead of UTC.

Comment: thx for the good explanation AND most of all: the answer to my question!

Comment: Uhm, glad you got the accepted answer but you basically copied text from mine :)

Answer (score 1):

The `2012-12-28T18:12:33+01:00` date string indicates that it is 2012-12-28 at 18:12 in the timezone that corresponds to +1 hour from UTC, which is CET timezone.

This appears to be the [ISO 8601 format](http://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime). The `T` indicates start of the time element.

> Times are expressed in local time, together with a time zone offset in
>   hours and minutes. A time zone offset of "+hh:mm" indicates that the
>   date/time uses a local time zone which is "hh" hours and "mm" minutes
>   ahead of UTC. A time zone offset of "-hh:mm" indicates that the
>   date/time uses a local time zone which is "hh" hours and "mm" minutes
>   behind UTC.

Comment: So to be sure: it is 2012-12-28 18:12 in Holland. I need to show some info about a transaction placed on 2012-12-28T18:12:33+01:00 by a Dutch person. What is the correct time to show? (sorry for being a noobn)

Comment: @iAmTheOneAndOnly - Then use [pytz](http://pytz.sourceforge.net/) for your timezone database.  There are also a lot of [existing questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/timezone+django) on  Django's own timezone support that might be useful.

Answer (score 1):

The value you provided `2012-12-28T18:12:33+01:00` is an [DateTime+Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datetimeoffset/info) value in [ISO8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iso8601) format, meaning "December 12th, 2013 at 18:12:33, one hour *ahead* of UTC".

The `+01:00` portion represents an *offset*, not a *time zone*.  See [TimeZone != Offset](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).

The time zone for Holland is either [`Europe/Amsterdam`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Amsterdam) in the IANA/Olson database, or the entry in the [Windows database](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/973627) that has the Id of `W. Europe Standard Time` and the English display name of "(UTC+01:00) Amsterdam, Berlin, Bern, Rome, Stockholm, Vienna".

This zone is in the `+01:00` offset during part of the year, and uses the `+02:00` offset during European Summer Time.

Just because you have `+01:00` in December, does not mean that is the correct offset to use year-round.  It also does not tell you that the timestamp is in Holland.  There are several other time zones that use the same offset, and not always at the same times of year.

To convert from one time zone to another, you need to first apply the offset you have.  Use the inverse of the sign you have.  Since you have `+01:00`, you would *subtract* an hour to get the UTC time of `17:12:33`.  Then you need to know what the correct offset is for the target time zone at that time of year.  For that, you need [a time zone database](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/datetimeoffset/info).